# C# X509Store Access Web Hosting

Tags: c#, ssl

I have an SSL cert stored in the Web Hosting Folder of the Certificate Store. I cannot seem to be able to access this store from C#. Does anyone know how to do this?

```
 X509Store store = new X509Store("Web Hosting");
 store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
 var t = store.Certificates.GetEnumerator();

 while (t.MoveNext())
 {
     //this is always empty
}
```

**Additional Detail**
I need this cert for a gRPC service that I am writing. gRPC requires a certificate for the SSL connection. In the mean time aka development I am using Let's Encrypt to generate the certificate. When the cert was generated the cert was put into the Web Hosting folder of the cert store.

Comment: SSL is obsolete.  You need to use TLS 1.2 or TLS 1.3.  What encryption mode is the key?  See following to determine if encryption is mode supported in TLS : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security

Comment: @jdweng See the additional detail section

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out you can drag and drop the certs to a different location in the cert manager. I relocated the cert to the Personal folder and I was able to access it by:

```
X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
```

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
var certStore = new X509Store("WebHosting");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the space; e.g., try the name as `webhosting` (no space)

In PowerShell, to display certs in this store location:

```
dir cert:\localmachine\webhosting
```